# 'YT' is not defined - Youtube Player API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I am using [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) on my React site. When I try it on the site, it gives this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined`. Here is the code I am using:

```
var player;
function loadVideo() {
    window.YT.ready(function () {
      new window.YT.Player("player", {
        height: "390",
        width: "640",
        videoId: "M7lc1UVf-VE",
        events: {
          onReady: onPlayerReady,
          onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange,
        },
      });
    });

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.playVideo();
      player = event.target;
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      var videoStatuses = Object.entries(window.YT.PlayerState);
      console.log(videoStatuses.find((status) => status[1] === event.data)[0]);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setMaxDuration("06:00");
    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    loadVideo();
  }, []);
```

Iframe:

```
  <div id="player">
    <iframe
      title="p"
      id="player"
      width="560"
      height="315"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sGPrx9bjgC8&autoplay=1"
      frameBorder="0"
      allowFullScreen
    ></iframe>
  </div>
```

(edited the code to the latest workaround)
How can I get this to work?

Comment: Is this script supposed to create a `YT` global variable?

Comment: I think it is. I followed this guide: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: `window.YT.Player(...)`

Comment: Now your problem is solved I reverted your question, according to this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377812/methods-to-remedy-a-chameleon-question-and-teach-the-op In general your question can evolve with debugging details but should not completely change. Your question will be more useful in its original state for future users that encounter the same problem. And we can discuss about my answer in the comments or in the chat instead of editing the question with its content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to load the library as suggested by the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). The code below loads the library asynchronously, then the library "calls back" your code when ready via the global `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` callback (the name is mandatory).

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  console.log('Yay, YT exists!', YT);
}
```

When doing a bit of reverse engineering in the YouTube library code we can see this line (unminified by myself):

```
const callback = window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
callback && callback();
```

Which shows how this function is being called and why it doesn't throw any error if it doesn't exist.

---

As I read your question again, you're using React, so the previous solution might not integrate very well, you might prefer not to use the global callback and use this instead:

```
const useYoutube = callback => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!window.YT) {
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      tag.onload = callback;
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }, []);
};
```

This custom hook will load the YouTube library only once, lazily (the first time it is needed). You could import it in every component that needs it, and use it with `useYoutube(loadVideo)`.

Here is a working [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ypdiw4)

Works also in local:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! But that also doesn't work. It gives this error: `'YT' is not defined`. The code I used is in the updated question.

Comment: The Interesting thing is that the object is consoled in the console even though the error is there

Comment: Can you try with `window.YT`? It looks like stackblitz is less restrictive about global variables.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error (see the edit) did you try `window.YT` in your `loadVideo` function?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the the object shows up in the console, is that the console runs asynchronously from you code. When you have the error YT is not yet loaded, but it has been by the time the console is displayed.

You can prove this be changing your console log to parse the object into a string with JSON.serialise() which will then log the runtime state of the object.